# Remapping KP_UP to Up

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, xkb

I am encountering weird issue with Android Studio, and it seems the fix will still take some time. When I press arrow keys at numeric keypad at the editor window, the cursor won't move. But it does move when I press the arrow keys at the middle group. The `xev` shows that the numeric pad cursor emits `KP_UP`, while the middle one shows `Up`.

I don't want to wait for the fix, so I want to remap the keyboard using `xkb` from `KP_Up` into `Up`. But so far, every time I change the `KP_Up`, it also removed `KP_8`. I need to remap only `KP_Up`, with State `0x0` (numlock off) but not `KP_8` with state `0x10` (Numlock on).

The OS is Ubuntu 23.04 with Wayland. Any idea on how I can do that?

Thank you for your help.